# How do I access Menu Tkinter via tcl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, menu, tcl

Good afternoon! I'm writing a Python program with the `Tkinter` GUI. I decided to rewrite one `ttk` theme for the sake of experiment. The entire program should be in dark colors, but the menu remains light colors. Then I decided to write the settings for `Menu` via the `tcl` file, but I could only find access to `Menubutton`, and I don't know how to access the settings of the `Menu` itself. Please help me.

### Update

I realized that I asked the question incorrectly. I need to change this menu in the window

[image]

And here it is

[image]

The screenshots show that the menu is gray, but I need to change the entire menu to black (and not just the menibutton, which changed in the second menu)

### Update 2

I found this link: https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Changing+Widget+Colors

There is such a code:

```
.menu configure -background color
.menu configure -foreground color
.menu configure -activebackground color
.menu configure -activeforeground color
.menu configure -disabledforeground color
.menu configure -font namedfont
.menu configure -selectcolor color
.menu configure -activeborderwidth size
```

As I understand it, here’s a way to change the menu itself through a tcl file, but I don’t know how to adapt this code and how to apply it to tune this menu bar.

[image]

PS Sorry for my clumsy English, but no one helped me on Russian-language forums. I had to go to extreme measures

Comment: [tk doc on menus](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/menus.html) may be useful.

Comment: @acw1668, but is it possible to somehow access the menu items like `tk :: mac :: ShowPreferences`, but on Windows?

Comment: @axw1668, that is, I need to somehow look at the settings of the tkinter menu or the menu that it uses and change them in the tcl file

Comment: @acw1668, Updated the question so that it is better to understand what I need

Comment: If you're doing Dark Mode on OSX, there were significant fixes fairly recently. I saw a great presentation on their implementation in November last year at a conference.

Comment: @DonalFellows, no, I'm working on Windows and writing a program for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying properties of a menu widget are [described here](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/menu.htm) (which hyperlinks to generic option descriptions elsewhere in some cases); they're mapped [directly into Tkinter](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm) but not described quite as well there. The option likely to be causing you a problem is probably one of:

- `-borderwidth`
- `-activeborderwidth`
- `-relief` (hopefully not this one; it's actively managed by menu bindings)

Try setting the first two to zero explicitly (they're normally zero anyway, but can pick up settings from other places via Xdefaults).

```
yourmenu.config(borderwidth=0, activeborderwidth=0)
```

The background itself is configured by the same method (`background="black"` will do it). You may need to experiment a bit to get it right.

---

If you're doing this for the whole application, you might want to look at setting these values via the Xdefaults. The Tkinter book does *not* document this well; the Tk documentation is [better](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/option.htm) but you still have to work things out by analogy as this part of the API is fairly obscure.

```
tk.option_add("*Menu.borderWidth", "0")
tk.option_add("*Menu.activeBorderWidth", "0")
tk.option_add("*Menu.background", "black")
# etc.
```

The key thing here is that you need to use the *option database name* (or *option database class name*) instead of the *option name* (which is listed on the menu page) and precede it with `*Menu.` so it applies to all menus created after you put this in the DB.

Comment: The option database is **only read when a widget is created.** After creation, you can only control them via configuration. (Also, configure options to a widget can be passed to its constructor. I assume you knew that already.)

Comment: Unfortunately everything remains in the same form to which I myself could bring all this

Comment: Most likely this should be configured through `tcl` files, as I was already given the answer that through `tkinter python` this is not possible

Answer (score 0):

Found a rather interesting way to create the main menu in Tkinter. You can create a Frame and put the Menubutton's, to which you can attach pop-up menus.

### Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

root.option_add("*Menu.borderWidth", "0")
root.option_add("*Menu.activeBorderWidth", "0")
root.option_add("*Menu.background", "black")


menu = tk.Menu(root)

btn_menu = tk.Menubutton(root, text='fegvd')
btn_menu.pack()


file = tk.Menu(btn_menu, tearoff=0, foreground='white')
file.add_command(label='ГЫГ')

btn_menu.configure(background='black', foreground='white', indicator=0, menu=file, state='active')

root.mainloop()
```

I did not find another way